# Password Validation using regular expressions in html 5

Tags: javascript, html5, validation

this question may sound stupid, but no one has ever taught me this. I have an HTML input for a password field, and you can only log on with one specific password with JS. Could someone please give me a syntax on assigning a variable to document.getElementById(""); syntax or a different syntax? Thanks.

Comment: I think you would be better asking these types of questions on stackoverflow.  This site is for more subjective questions about programming, not specific language features.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess you are trying to use password in your page. If the purpose of registration is to confirm that the person exists and has supplied a valid email address then at the first instance you should email them a random password rather than having them choose their own and use it immediately.

Here is a good article that walks you through [JavaScript: Password Validation using regular expressions and HTML5](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/javascript/validate-password/).

In addition you may get a wealth of information about `HTML DOM Password Object` [here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/dom_obj_password.asp).

Comment: I just did! I recently gained that advantage!

Comment: Sure, what were they titled?

Comment: @CodingSeahawks, thx, they all titled as HTML5 questions that you have asked today. look at your Questions list - http://programmers.stackexchange.com/users/64280/coding-seahawks

Comment: I just did that. But you did not answer 1 html5 question. :)

Comment: well that question is closed. i am not able to put any answer there. what mobile phone r u using?

Comment: iPad not a mobile phone